# How to create an endeless / moveable Layout? "endless paper"-Metapher

Tags: android, android-layout

how do i create an endless / movable layout, which is endless/movable in all directions? 
I want to develop an app to create diagrams, and if the  diagram gets too big i want it to be movable in all directions.

I hope its understandable.

with regards

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw);



        _root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.draw);
        _view = new ImageView(this);
        _view.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenbutton);
        BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greenbutton);
        int height=bd.getBitmap().getHeight();
        int width=bd.getBitmap().getWidth();

        /*MyScrollView myV = new MyScrollView(this);
        myV.setLayoutParams(_root.getLayoutParams());*/

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(height,width);
        _view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        _view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                        _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                        layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                        layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                        v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                }
                _root.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        });
        //myV.addView(_view);
        _root.addView(_view);
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".Draw">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/draw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_grid">

    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/mostUsedBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </GridView>
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/elementBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"></GridView>
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/relBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"></GridView>



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried so far and why did it not work.

Comment: i googled a lot :) but i didn't find anything. I also tried to use "OnTouch" but that also didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view that scrolls (do it manually) and keep everything in two variables let's say scrollX and scrollY (assume the point at the top left point of the screen). So draw everything on top with an offset of scrollX and scrollY.

Here is some code:

```
public class MyScrollView extends View
{
    private int scrollX, scrollY;
    private int pinPointX, pinPointY;

    public MyScrollView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        //Initialize scroll to look at the top left edge of the "paper"
        scrollX = 0;
        scrollY = 0;
    }

    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //Mark touch point
                pinPointX = (int) e.getX();
                pinPointY = (int) e.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //Scroll view
                scrollX += (int) e.getX() -pinPointX;
                scrollY += (int) e.getY() -pinPointY;

                //Mark new point
                pinPointX = (int) e.getX();
                pinPointY = (int) e.getY();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Draw everything here with an offset of scrollX, scrollY
    }
}
```

Sorry I may have made some mistakes (mainly with android's class names) but I wrote the code on the go, if u see any minor mistake make sure to correct it.

Note that this code will allow you to scroll "infinitely" at least as long as scrollX and scrollY remain on their int limits (from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647) you can keep it like that since nobody will scroll that far, but I'd recommend applying some limits just to make the app more "perfect".

Also I'm not sure but I think this code may have some issue if you scroll to the negative side (leftwards and upwards - when scrollX and/or scrollY are negative) but I may be wrong.

If you want to include more views (like a layout that you ask) make it a `ViewGroup` but I don't have much experience using that. I showed you a logic to follow it's up to you to attach it to your code as you like.

Comment: You can use `GestureDetector` to detect some touch gestures, like flings, which aren't detected by code above. Also you can use built-in scrolling support of Android Widget Framework.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Scrolling

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how do i Implement this?

Comment: @Haja I wrote a code that shows you the logic of how to make it, it's up to you to figure out how to implement it on your code, if you show us some more code maybe i can help a little more, but I know nothing about your project so there is little i can do to help

Comment: Hello TomTsagk, right now i don't have any real code, iam just experimenting with the Problems i have.  But I will edit my post with the code i have right now.